# Google Sheets Apps Script to translate GBK encoding to UTF-8

Tags: google-apps-script, character-encoding

I am trying to paste a piece of text in Chinese Simplified Character into Google Sheets and convert it into UTF-8 with an Apps Script custom function. The original text is in some kind of GBK encoding format.

```
function gbk2utf8(strInput,inputChartset="gbk",outputCharset="utf-8"){
  return Utilities.newBlob("").setDataFromString(strInput, inputChartset).getDataAsString(outputCharset);
}
```

When I run this function, I tested it with Row 2 to make sure that it works generally.

But when I paste the Chinese Simplified Character with GBK encoding, it does not work as I try various encoding for the input string as shown in Row 3 to Row 6 in the picture.

[image]

As you can tell I have tried "gbk", "gb2312", "gb2312-80", "gb18030". None of them works. I also tried "gb13000" just to make sure that the script show error if I input an invalid charset code.

Wonder what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Unfortunately GBK is not supported as a charset by the method [setDataFromString(string, charset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob?hl=en#setdatafromstringstring,-charset)

The only supported enums are `US_ASCII` and `UTF_8` - see [Enum Charset](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/charset):

[image]